# Should the Movies & TV SE have a "suggested order" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Over on the [Sci-Fi & Fantasy SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) they have a ["suggested order"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suggested-order) tag which is used for questions where people ask for the order in which they should consume a certain franchise.

Considering that this SE also has a number of those, would it make sense to introduce a similar tag here, e.g. for questions like ["In what order should I watch the X-Men movies?"](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/52703/in-what-order-should-i-watch-the-x-men-movies)?

Comment: Hmm, while a reasonable idea, `suggested order` as a tagname sounds a little too narrowing, since I'd also like to beat the occasional *"do I need to have seen that to understand this?"* question with the new tag, which while essentially also asking for a (partial) order is a little less obviously labeled with "suggested order".

Comment: In almost all cases these aren't good questions, because the best answer is "in the order in which they were released", or they are heavily opinion-based.

Comment: @OrangeDog Your point is a good one in most cases. Sometimes release order is different from *intended* order, with *Firefly* being the canonical example of how release order is probably the worst order in which to see something, and there is an objective (non-opinion) basis for that.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I agree that those questions can make **reasonable questions with answers that might reveal interesting approaches** to a series of films. The answers to such questions, while not necessarily having the *one true 100% correct viewing order* among them, can still very well be backed by reasonable arguments that do *not* have to devolve into mere subjective opinion-pieces, even when arguing against both chronological and release order. As long as you can provide explanations in which way a suggested order adds to the understanding of the story, the appreciation of its themes, or the discovery of new interesting connections and don't just say that you *"enjoyed watching it this way"* or that *"half the movies are crap anyway and can be left out"*. The lack of a single 100% correct answer is *not* necessarily a bad thing. This doesn't mean that those questions don't offer the possibility to attract opinionated non-answers and shouldn't be kept under close surveillance (and possible protection if misuse becomes apparent). But many interesting questions present that danger.

That being said, *if* we decide to introduce a tag for them, I would like to slap it onto more than plain *"in what order should I watch this series?"* questions. We also now and then have **questions of the form *"should I watch this to understand this?"***, which even by "suggested order" detractors could be argued to be more objectively reasonable than plain suggested order questions. While they could be argued to ask for a *partial* order, too, they aren't necessarily asking for a "suggested order" to watch a whole series. So I would like the tag to reflect those kinds of questions, too, and I'm not yet sure the name `suggested-order` really does that.

As of now we have quite a few of the "classic" full order requests:

- [In what order should a newcomer watch Star Wars episodes?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/2063/49)
- [What is the best order to watch LotR/Hobbit franchise?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/28221/49)
- [In what order should I watch the X-Men movies?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/52703/49)
- [Best order to watch the Underworld movie series](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/26773/49)
- [What is the best order to watch Batman animated movies?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/52608/49)
- [Battlestar galatica movies and series watch order](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/36142/49)
- [In what order should I watch The planet of the Apes franchise?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/50615/49)
- [Does it matter in which order I watch the "Man With No Name" trilogy?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/353/49) (This merely asks *if* there even is a significant order at all, but could still be counted as "suggested order" question.)

And then there are also a few "partial order" questions, or making sense of material without having seen the previous installments:

- [Do I need to watch the Hannibal movies before I watch the show?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/19512/49)
- [Any significance to watching The Originals for understanding The Vampire Diaries and if yes then in which order?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/51289/49)
- [How far back do I need to watch Doctor Who for it to still make sense?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/19727/49)

However, we should be careful to separate those questions against questions that as for a hard order of chronology within the story, which is *not* necessarily the answer to each of the above suggested order questions. Thos would rather be tagged [chronology](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chronology) and are quite different to "suggested order" questions in their essece. I would count all of those questions listed above as "suggested order" questions.

**So to sum up:** Yes, I think a tag for those questions could be a good idea, but I would like to use it for more than full order questions about a series and would like the tag name to reflect that, which I'm not sure `suggested-order` does sufficiently.